# Angular.js and ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am new bee to `angular.js` and `ng-table`. I have drop down list which consist of two values on the same page in which the table is displayed.

Each value of the drop down can have a table of data with pagination.The default value will be on the drop down and according to that value the table will be shown(call it as old table).

I was trying to hide the table if the valued changed in the drop down. To do this
I have used:

```
ng-hide directive.
```

The table hides correctly but still pagination is on the page. So that i can see one table with two pagination.

If i change the value of the drop down, the old table should be hidden with its pagination. The new table should show with its corresponding pagination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it might be helpful if you post more code e.g. you could make a minimal example and post it as a gist on github if it is too big to fit in this page. also you should run it in firefox or chrome with developer view and post any errors that the browser says it is having trying to run you code.

Comment: The `ng-hide` directive has to include all you want to hide or show, that is, the table and the paginator. Add it a level up in the DOM or add an auxiliary `<div ng-hide="your condition">` including both elements. But I'm just guessing. As @simbo1905 said, some code will help.